# CSS tint image with rounded edges with no overflow

Tags: css, hover

I am trying to tint images onHover. I have the css working but some of the images which have rounded edges or don't completely fill the parent show the black background:
[image]

(The far left has the mouse over it)

How can hide the black so only the img is tinted?

Here is my css:

```
.thumb {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    margin: 0px 5px 14px 14px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
background: black;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*border: 2px solid #00A3C6; */
}

.thumb img {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.25s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.25s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.25s linear;
            transition: all 0.25s linear;

}

.thumb:hover img { 
    opacity: 0.7;
}​
```

Comment: what is the markup you're using for these?

Comment: The "tint" has no idea what's actually in the image. Without setting all of these up manually, I don't know how you expect CSS to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image has rounded corners, you can use `border-radius` in your css to set rounded corners of the "tint" container.

If the actual image has a white border... you're kind of out of luck. You can [crop](http://cssglobe.com/3-easy-and-fast-css-techniques-for-faux-image/) images but you don't have any way to doing this dynamically for any kind of image.

Answer (score 0):

> How can hide the black so only the img is tinted?

Try removing `background: black` from `.thumb` ?

P.S. `display: inline` is also not needed there